# Dax Formula to Distinct Count Prior Month's Subscriptions based on Item Groups

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the following Data:

```
declare @tbl    table   (
                            id int primary key identity
                        ,   Months varchar(30)
                        ,   RepName varchar(50)
                        ,   Targets float
                        ,   DefaultCommision float
                        ,   [Target%] float
                        ,   Sales float
                        ,   CommPayable float
                        ,   NumberOfSubscriptions float
                        ,   PriorMonthNumberOfSubscriptions float
                        )

insert into @tbl    (
                        Months
                    ,   RepName
                    ,   Targets
                    ,   DefaultCommision
                    ,   [Target%]
                    ,   Sales
                    ,   CommPayable
                    ,   NumberOfSubscriptions
                    ,   PriorMonthNumberOfSubscriptions
                    )

values
('February','Samantha Proctor-Parker',3800000,12600,1.3,4939855.81999999,17639,18,23),
('January','Samantha Proctor-Parker',3800000,12600,1.26,4800158.64,16713,20,23),
('February','Jean-Pierre Jacobsz',3900000,12900,1.09,4254781.79000002,12667,20,21),
('February','Happiness Ngobese',3200000,10800,1.14,3637103.42000003,11590,19,31),
('January','Jean-Pierre Jacobsz',3900000,12900,0.9,3506961.34000002,9280,19,21),
('January','Happiness Ngobese',3200000,10800,1.07,3426711.32000004,10170,20,31),
('February','Paul Samuel',3700000,12300,0.7,2589926.67999999,6888,12,22),
('January','Paul Samuel',3700000,12300,0.7,2573206.72,6843,12,22),
('February','Brandon Singh',4100000,13500,0.63,2572022.62000001,6775,16,21),
('January','Brandon Singh',4100000,13500,0.61,2490206.50000001,6560,14,21),
('February','Shaun Lubbe',3600000,12000,0.67,2404381.37000001,6412,17,23),
('January','Shaun Lubbe',3600000,12000,0.62,2228099.32000001,5942,16,23),
('February','Chantelle Ashman',3500000,11700,0.61,2117928.55,5664,14,25),
('January','Chantelle Ashman',3500000,11700,0.56,1972150.63,5274,14,25),
('February','Lizel Mashile',4000000,13200,0.41,1654731.25000001,4368,14,20),
('January','Lizel Mashile',4000000,13200,0.38,1532456.93000002,4046,14,20),
('January','Darren Fisher',1200000,4800,1.05,1258980.32,4312,17,23),
('February','Darren Fisher',1200000,4800,1.03,1241665.64,4173,16,23),
('February','Gurschzon Lewis',4200000,13800,0.17,731974.850000019,1924,11,14),
('January','Gurschzon Lewis',4200000,13800,0.17,693703.060000018,1823,10,14),
('January','House Account',1800000,6600,0.35,625220.740000012,1834,9,24),
('February','Sibusiso Simandla',4300000,14100,0.1,423887.620000002,1112,9,10),
('February','Nomsa Mashike',4400000,14400,0.09,415213.830000005,1087,8,8),
('January','Sibusiso Simandla',4300000,14100,0.09,365857.090000001,960,9,10),
('January','Nomsa Mashike',4400000,14400,0.08,358852.240000002,940,6,8),
('February','House Account',1800000,6600,0.13,229197.950000012,672,11,24)

select
*
from    @tbl
```

The above sample data, provides me with this results:

[image: Current Data]

I tried using DAX with this formula : `SubscriptionsPriorMonth = calculate(DISTINCTCOUNT(EvolutionSales[ItemGroup]),edate('Date'[Date],-1))`

But the problem I'm facing is, it's not counting correctly.

I need the same result as the `Number of Subscriptions`, except, it needs to be for the **Prior Month**.

My expected Result is as following:

[image: Expected Results]

Please advise how I should alter my formula to cater for this?

Comment: can you share your data model?

Comment: Agreed, that would be very helpful. Currently, it's hard to see the relationship between [Months] column (text) and 'Date'[Date] that is being used in the expression. Also, could you please explain what EvolutionSales[ItemGroup] is, I cannot see it on any of the screenshots.

Comment: Christian Welsch and Justyna MK, thank you for your reply.

Unfortunately, the data model contains some sensitive financial information to a corporate enterprise.

Essentially my issue is as follows:

I have a data model displaying data as shown per screen shot above.

The data displayed currently is upon selecting both Jan & Feb on a slicer.

As described I tried implementing a Dax formula which will allow me to select only one month on the slicer but still have the column for Subscriptions Prior Month.

If this is vague, pleas advise and I will try and elaborate even further.